# Same regex but giving different result with StringTokenizer and Scanner class delimiter

Tags: java, regex, regular-language

Im trying to separate each word in the sentence using `StringTokenizer` class. It works fine for me. But I found another solution to my case using `Scanner` class.I applied same regular expression in both ways but got different result. I would like to know the reason for different out put I got but with same expression. 
**Here is my code :**

```
String sentence = "I have some problems with this section!"
        + " But I love to learn.";


StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(sentence, "[! ]");
System.out.println("========Using StringTokenizer=========");
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    System.out.println(st.nextToken());
}


Scanner s = new Scanner(sentence);
s.useDelimiter("[! ]");
System.out.println("========Using Delimiter=========");
while (s.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(s.next());

}
```

**Out-put form StringTokenizer:**

```
========Using StringTokenizer=========
I
have
some
problems
with
this
section
But
I
love
to
learn.
```

**Out-put using Scanner class  :**

```
========Using Delimiter=========
I
have
some
problems
with
this
section

But
I
love
to
learn.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `Scanner` may match an empty `String`, while `StringTokonizer` will not. In this case in the part *"section! But"* `Scanner` matches the whitespace after the `!` symbol, whereas `StringTokenizer` does not.

Comment: with `s.useDelimiter("[! ]+");` I got the same result in Scanner as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Scanner** includes empty matches while **StringTokenizer** does not.

**StringTokenizer** can't properly parse delimited files with meaningful indexed columns/fields like **/etc/passwd** or CSVs for this reason because it will not return all of the columns/fields while **Scanner** will.